# Text intermittently is warped, garbled in 12.04 LTS

Tags: window, text

After upgrading to 12.04 LTS, text on screen (both in Unity and Gnome-Shell 3.4) becomes garbled, particularly in window title bars and in fields. This does not apply to all text on screen, just text that is being actively edited, or window titles that have changed in any way.

[image]

`lspci` output

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port B) (rev 02)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port B)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port D)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port E)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port F)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port G)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port H)
00:0a.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx1 port A)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cypress XT [Radeon HD 5870]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Cypress HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5800 Series]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
03:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
04:00.0 SATA controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB362 SATA Controller (rev 10)
05:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
06:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR5418 Wireless Network Adapter [AR5008E 802.11(a)bgn] (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
07:00.0 SATA controller: JMicron Technology Corp. JMB362 SATA Controller (rev 10)
08:06.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller (rev c0)
```

Graphics card: AMD/ATi Radeon HD5870

Comment: It will be helpful if you can edit your question and add some information about your hardware, specifically about your graphics. Hare's a [guide](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into). Thanks!

Comment: I have encountered the same issue on my nVidia GTX 460M / ubuntu 12.10, so it seems it isn't an issue with the graphics card.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).